# Detect OK Google hotword on the watch face service

Tags: android, command, wear-os, voice, watch-face-api

I would like implement a functionality "OK Google" on Android Wear watch face service, so the watch face has ability to check the hotword from user and do something based on that word. Does it possible at all, since the watch face doesn't have Activity based to Google doc?

Kind regards.
Tnx